# mod_jk - Unable to get the free endpoint

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat6, mod-jk

Im using Apache/2.2.14 (Worker MPM) + libapache2-mod-jk 1.2.28-2 + tomcat 6.0.24 for my app to work with CGI and Java, together on a single machine. I am experiencing an issue with mod_jk (I'm not sure):

**Error**

```
Internal Server Error
[info] "ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3001): Unable to get the free endpoint for worker ajp13 from 10 slots" 
[error] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2549): Could not get endpoint for worker=ajp13
```

This is only happening, when I am using a remote Proxy server. Direct connections seem to be working.

**jk_workers.properties:**

```
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.lbfactor=50
worker.ajp13.cachesize=10
worker.ajp13.cache_timeout=600
worker.ajp13.socket_keepalive=1
```

**mods-enabled/jk.conf**

```
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/jk_workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
JkShmFile /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the [deprecated cachesize property](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html#Deprecated%20Worker%20Directives) and test it again.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did remove cachesize & cache_timeout from jk_workers.properties and it works.. :-)